# Laravel 5 override route resource parameters

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I'm using some web routes behind a resource controller. So the route looks simply like:

```
Route::resource('account', 'AccountController');
```

I also have a web middleware that checks if a `user_id` parameter is set in the `Request` object:

```
if ($request->user_id) {
    // do stuff
}
```

The problem is this. In my non-resource routes I use something like:

```
Route::get('agentnotes/{user_id}', 'UserNoteController@getUserNotes');
```

This sets the `user_id` variable as expected, and the middleware functions fine.

But in the resource routes, even though the actual route method uses the `user_id`, the middleware isn't seeing it. So for example, the `AccountController::show` method looks like this:

```
public function show($user_id)
```

But the middleware doesn't see that `user_id` as part of the request, I assume because it's already fired before the request gets to the controller.

Is there a way to handle this without rewriting all the resource routes?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

According to the Laravel docs:

> By default, Route::resource will create the route parameters for your resource routes based on the "singularized" version of the resource name. You can easily override this on a per resource basis by passing parameters in the options array.

So I had to override the default values using my `user_id` that the middleware expected.

```
Route::resource('account', 'AccountController', ['parameters' => [
    'account' => 'user_id'
]]);
```

Comment: great! I was having a very bad day because my controller was looking for a wrongly singularized resource name... thanks!